# Likely cause for surprising Typescript initialisation error

Tags: typescript

I'm getting the compiler error `Property 'options' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.` but as you can see from the start of the class in question, the stated error does not reflect reality.

```
export class DocumentRenderer {

    options: IDocumentRenderer;

    public DocumentRenderer(options: IDocumentRenderer) {
        this.options = options;
    }

...
```

What else can cause this to be reported? I could understand this if there were other constructors that fail to set the member, but there is only one constructor.

---

### This was a doofus user error.

However, it is very common to switch between C# and Typescript in the same web application, so the mistake will happen eventually. The fact that C# constructor syntax is legal as Typescript method syntax makes the reported error quite confusing.

I wrote up an answer to help others who've made the same mistake. Finding this makes for a facepalm quick and easy fix.

Kindly refrain from making it hard to find via downvotes. If you're too awesome to ever make this mistake, then move on to something more worthy of your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I've used C# constructor syntax.

This is valid Typescript method syntax. It doesn't produce editor squigglies or warnings on the "constructor" that's actually a method, so it is not obvious that there is actually no constructor here.

The default constructor does not set the property, thus the error.

I [suggested raising a warning](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51296) to the Typescript team but it seems the Typescript compiler doesn't support the notion of warnings. After some discussion I decided that I'll have to write an ESLint rule.

Comment: Well actually I've done the opposite before and I tried using `constructor(...)` in C#. Does this mean I also get to complain to Anders about this too? :')

Comment: I closed the warning suggestion because it seems the best outcome would be a new rule for ESLint. This will both call it out and offer a fix in VS Code. I don't know what to suggest for C#. Is CSLint a thing?